# How to use Angular Materials in a single component of my Angular TS application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm building off of an existing Angular TS project, one that does not use Angular Materials for it's styling/functionality. For my page the Materials package provides the functionality I want and need, but I do not want the styling to affect any of the other components in the project.

In one of my branches I had installed and set up Materials which affected the entire project and messed up numerous different stylings that had been created, so I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Can you show any code at all from this project?  It's pretty difficult to give help with zero code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

****What version of angular are you using?**

You should be able to use Angular Material components without necessarily applying the Material styles across your entire application. Here's a way to use Angular Material in your component while minimizing the effect on other components:

1. **Install Angular Material** as usual:

> ```
> ng add @angular/material
> ```

2. Import **only the specific modules** you need:

In the module where your component is declared, import only the Angular Material modules that you need. For example, if you're using a button and a checkbox, you would import only those modules:

```js
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ... other imports
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  // ...
})
export class YourModule { }
```

3. Avoid including the Material pre-built themes:
   In your angular.json or global styles file, make sure you don't include any of the Material pre-built themes, as they would apply across the entire application. If they are already included in a global styles file, you may want to remove or comment them out.

For example, **AVOID lines like this**:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```